# Should I format my SSD on my macbook pro

Tags: macos, ssd, formatting, trim

I have a macbook pro with an SSD. Would formatting my hard drive make a difference from a speed perspective seeing as how OS X doesn't support TRIM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there will be no speed difference if you reformat.

"across the majority of our tests, there's very little difference between the clean ssd and the one that's been used."
http://www.bit-tech.net/hardware/apple/2010/07/01/mac-ssd-performance-trim-in-osx/1

"even without support for the trim command, ssd flies on mac os x"
http://www.hardmac.com/news/2010/05/06/even-without-support-for-the-trim-command-ssd-flies-on-mac-os-x